# Merge multiple rows into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following output:

```
ObjectNumber  Field1  Field2  Field3
------------------------------------
      1         1       0       0
      1         0       0       1
      2         0       0       0
      2         1       0       0
      2         0       1       1
```

I need to "merge" these rows into 1 row per ObjectNumber. Assume that

1. all Fields have either `0` or `1` as value and
2. per ObjectNumber there is only one `1` per field

The expected output is adding up all the fields:

```
ObjectNumber  Field1  Field2  Field3
------------------------------------
      1         1       0       1
      2         1       1       1
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is it trying to output the sum for each column group by the ObjectNumber ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case both max() en sum() will work, but sum() seems more appropriate since you say that the output is 'adding up all the fields'.

```
SELECT ObjectNumber,
       sum(Field1) AS Field1,
       sum(Field2) AS Field2,
       sum(Field3) AS Field3
FROM youroutput t
GROUP BY ObjectNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an aggregation query with `max()`:

```
select ObjectNumber, max(Field1) as Field1, max(Field2) as Field2, max(Field3) as Field3
from youroutput t
group by ObjectNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was required to add up the number, we might have to use sum

```
Select objectnumber,
       Sum(field1) as field1,
       Sum(field2) as field2,
       Sum(field3) as field3
From  product
Group by objectnumber
```